# TypeScript config typeRoots and types not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, tsconfig

### Current Setup

Here is my directory structure:

```sh
root
├──typings/           # currently empty
├──package.json
├──package-lock.json
├──tsconfig.json
└──main.ts
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "./typings"
        ],
        "types": ["Phaser"]  
    }    
}
```

Here is my `main.ts` file:

```
let countdownNumber: Phaser.GameObjects.BitmapText;
```

Then I've run the following command in terminal:

```sh
tsc --traceResolution
```

I am trying to use `Phaser` as a global variable in my `main.ts` file.

#### Expected behavior:

What should happen is `Phaser` shouldn't get resolved because compiler should start looking into my custom folder `typings`.

#### Actual behavior:

Somehow it still gets resolved. And this is what it prints:

> Type reference directive 'Phaser' was successfully resolved to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phasertest/node_modules/Phaser/types/phaser.d.ts' with Package ID 'phaser/types/phaser.d.ts@3.22.0', primary: false.

I don't know how it finds it since in my `typeRoots`, I don't have `node_modules` specified.

#### What I have tried:

I tried to exclude `node_modules` folder, I thought maybe they still get compiled and that's why this happens, but I couldn't make `exclude` work with any of the following:

- `"exclude": ["node_modules/*"]`
- `"exclude": ["./node_modules/*"]`
- `"exclude": ["./node_modules"]`

but none of these worked.

Comment: It's possible [Automatic Type Acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_7#_languages) could interfere as well?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is expected behavior, although I'd agree it's not super intuitive

According to the `tsconfig` docs on [Types > What does this affect?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#what-does-this-affect)

> This option does not affect how `@types/*` are included in your application code, for example if you had the above > `compilerOptions` example with code like:
>
> ```
> import * as moment from "moment";
> moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
> ```
>
> The `moment` import would be fully typed.
>
> When you have this option set, by not including a module in the types array it:
>
> - Will not add globals to your project (e.g process in node, or expect in Jest)
> - Will not have exports appear as auto-import recommendations